# Set ID as incremental variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

This is a long shot, as I'm not sure if this can even be done, so if it cannot, any suggestions as to an approach are appreciated.

I have an accordion within my HTML, where each contains a section of my XML document. To get the accordion to set the sections and apply them to open and close each section, I need to assign a number variable as the ID to each one. My accordion code in the HTML is as below:

```
<article class="accordion">

        <section id="start">

            <h2 id="title"><a href="#start"></a></h2>
            <p id="text"></p>
            <p id="quote"></p>
            <p id="link"></p>

            <b id="foot"><p id="date"></p></b>
            <b id= "foot"><p id="tags"></p></b>

        <section>
        </article>
```

Each part is set within my JavaScript file, which is appending the data correctly for the first one from viewing the output elsewhere, but is not visible as it cannot be clicked on without the variable.
My JavaScript contains, the below as a snippet of the title, and I am wondering if there is a way to use the variable i in my HTML? They are separate files rather than the JavaScript being in the HTML file.

```
var count = 1;

    for(i=0; i<x.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("start").id = count;

        title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postTitle")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title;

        count = count + 1;
    }
```

From testing the accordion by other means, I know it works, I just need to set the variable to be able to get it to work in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you declare the variable x?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to ask but this is a fair guess, IMO.

Using jQuery you can use `.each()` to target each child element of a containing parent.

```
$('.accordion').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'i' + i);
});
```

Note that in your example your elements were already assigned an ID and that this would overwrite the existing IDs.

Comment: I tried the JavaScript document.getElementById(i).id = count; to change the ID without much luck. For some reason the link for the title isn't working either, just isn't showing as a link.

Comment: So your actual problem is that you're unable to change the ID?

Comment: I've got it to change the ID actually now, I'd mis typed the Element ID. But I seem to be having bigger issues, mainly the title isn't showing as a link. Edited question above with the changes I made.

Comment: When you say "isn't showing as a link" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: <h2 id="title"><a href="#start"></a></h2> when the value is set, is not a clickable link as it should be

Comment: It's not clickable as there's no content in it. Note that the text should be added to it as a text node and not as a value attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69260/discussion-between-navvy-and-locercus).

Answer (score 0):

This will overwrite any set `id`, don't forget to open your dev console to see the actual change: http://jsfiddle.net/g2wf0gt4/

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<div id="hi"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

javascript

```
(function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i].setAttribute('id', [i]);
        console.log(x[i]);
    }   
    })();
```